# Script Assertion not running when request failed[Connection refused] in request log and no response in soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

Script assertion in my API request is not running when request log shows Connection refused and there is no reponse.

This happens when i run the test case as a set with multiple steps and if i run the API step manually, the assertion seems to work?

How come?

I want the script assertion to run even if the request fails as i am reading the Error log of ReadyAPI via groovy script and doing an assertion

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you experience differing behaviour, but if you have something you want to run regardless of the outcome of the test, you may want to consider moving it to the setup/teardown sections of that teststep...?